# Localization not showing default language

Tags: objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I am having a hard time figuring out why when I change the language of the device to a language that I don't support, it shows the incorrect localization. Let me explain myself better.

I have 2 languages supported by the app: 
1. English (Should be the primary)
2. Spanish

Now, the localization works perfectly when using either of them but lets say I change to Chinese (Which I don't have localization files or support) or any other language, then the device is showing Spanish localization. [image]

I don't want spanish localization to show when using a different language outside spanish! I want english to always show if the language of the device is not spanish.

By the way, I have deleted the app from the simulator and cleared all targets etc before testing. I am using the iOS simulator.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your app's info.plist file for the `Localization native development region`, or the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`.  If you don't support the device language, the OS can try to default back to the developer language.  My guess is this key is `es` for Spanish.  You want it to be `en` for English.